# pass selected value to another class Android

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, android-intent, android-spinner

I am trying to pass a value selected from spinner to another class but it passes null.

```
protected int secondsToUse;

final String titles[] = {
  "1 Second","2 Seconds", "3 Seconds","4 Seconds",
  "5 Seconds","6 Seconds","7 Seconds","8 Seconds","9 Seconds","10 Seconds"
};

mSeconds = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.secondsSpinner);

 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titles);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSeconds.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
mSeconds.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // secondsToUse is declared a as int variable above
            secondsToUse = position + 1;
        }



// passing the value to another class.// PASSES AS NULL
Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipientsActivity.class);
                    recipientsIntent.putExtra("key1", secondsToUse);
                    startActivity(recipientsIntent);

// retrieving the value //retrieves as null
String Seconds = getIntent().getStringExtra("key1");
byte[] secs = Seconds.getBytes();
```

i am trying to get the the position the user selects on the spinner so i can pass it into a timer for images to self destruct. at the moment i get null

Comment: make secondsToUse  to static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I forgot to take into account that `getIntExtra()` takes **two** arguments in my first answer. It requires an identifying "key" and a default value.

To retrieve the position of the selected row in `RecipientsActivity`, leave your code as it is. Then, in `onCreate()` of `RecipientsActivity`:

```
int seconds = getIntent().getIntExtra("key1", -1);
```

---

Comment: @smithyy If you want to pass the position, then you would be best served by using an `int` value. Of course, you need to use it consistently (all variables are `int`, you use `getIntExtra()` etc.). Let me make an update to my answer.

Comment: @smithyy Take a look at the edit at the top of my answer. Should resolve your issue.

Comment: its not allowing me to put putIntExtra() it says can not resolve method

Comment: @smithyy My apologies, you're correct. Use `putExtra()` instead, I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: it says getIntExtra can not be applied to string when i put `int seconds = getIntent().getIntExtra("key1");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87654/discussion-between-ppartisan-and-smithyy).

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace  `getStringExtra()` by `getIntExtra()`

```
int defaultSecond = -1;
int seconds = getIntent().getIntExtra("key1",defaultSecond);
```

**Reason:** Because you are putting a `int` not a `String` in `putExtra("key1", secondsToUse);`

Also, use camel case in naming a variable. Use seconds instead of Seconds.
I hope this helps!

Comment: i get error when getIntExtra and pass in "key1" as it says its incompatible, values still passes as null. i want the position the user selects in the spinner and then pass that on

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `getStringExtra()`?

You are passing an integer so receive an integer

```
// retrieving the value
int seconds = getIntent().getIntExtra("key1");
```

If you need it as a String use

```
String secondsAsString = String.valueOf(seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getStringExtra()` by `getIntExtra()`

```
int default = -1;
String val = getIntent().getIntExtra("key1",default);
if(val == default){
  //Log, exception, no value etc.
}
String Seconds = String.valueOf(val);
byte[] secs = Seconds.getBytes();
```

call start `Activity` when element selected from `ListView`

```
mSeconds.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // secondsToUse is declared a as int variable above
            secondsToUse = position + 1;
            // passing the value to another class.// PASSES AS NULL
            Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),     RecipientsActivity.class);
            recipientsIntent.putExtra("key1", secondsToUse);
            startActivity(recipientsIntent);
        }
```

Comment: still passes as null. i want the position the user selects in the spinner

Answer (score 0):

Call your next Activity with Explicit Intent inside OnItemSelectListner 
try This

mSeconds.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View selectedItemView, int

position, long id) {

```
               secondToUse = String.valueOf(position + 1);
               Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this,NewClass.Class);
               putInentExtra("Key1","secondTouse");
               startActivity(intent);

        }
```

And in your next Activity get Intent By-

Intent i= getIntent();

String getPosition= i.getStringExtra("Key1");

enjoy :)